How are ethereum transaction sent over the wire in Network to peers
I understand how ethereum transactions are signed and proapagated. But while comparing the output of rawTransaction with the wireshark capture of Etherum EOA transaction, I could not map the transaction data. Can someone please explain what and how are these transactions sent over the wire to its peers.
